# Unable To Create Virtual Directory Local IIS

Tags: c#, .net, iis, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to get my Backend API running again since I got an IP change. The directory is **virtual** no actual files are in there.

I used to have my backend set up with IIS and everything worked fine untill I got a new IP adress. I went into IIS to change my site there to the new IP, but when  I tried to create the virutal directory in Visual Studio I constantly get a 'Unable to create the virtual directory' error message. I have tried all sorts of ports, but neither work.

The Virtual Directory I am creating here is just a plain Web API, not used for accessing storage.

[image: Error Message]

As you can see, my IIS should be configured normally but still VS gives me the error. Thoughts?

Kind regards
Jasper

Comment: Clients only have GUEST privileges on IIS.  You virtual directory has to be a Network Drive that Client have read permission (and write).  When changing properties you have to login to IIS to make changes.

Comment: But it worked just fine with my previous IP?

Comment: I didn't say the Network Drive was on the IIS.  You need a shared folder on any machine where the folder allows GUEST accounts read/write privilege.   A network drive is a drive on a machine that allows shared privileges.

Comment: I use admin priv to set up the Virtual Directory in VS so it shouldn't be a problem

Comment: Either there is no route to your IP or the folder is not shared with correct privileges.  You need ADMIN privileges at the IP address.  I would first test with a window file explorer to see if you can access the folder and files before trying with c# code.

Answer (score 1):

You can follow the steps below to make it work.

1. Close the visual studio and open the project folder.
2. Find “.vs” folder(it may be hidden), there’s a applicationhost.config file in the subfolder and open it.
3. You can find a site tag similar to the following.

   ```
   <site name="your project name" id="your site id">
           <application path="/" applicationPool="Clr4IntegratedAppPool">
               <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="your project path" />
           </application> 
           <bindings>
               <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="your original binding information" /> 
           </bindings>
       </site>
   ```
4. Add a binding tag in bindings.

   ```
     <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:80:192.168.0.196" />
   ```

Here is my test result
[image]

Comment: I think it worked, but is this still the same as using Local IIS because this setting only works on Express IIS

Comment: If you choose local IIS, I am very sorry that you cannot create a virtual directory through ip, because local IIS is aimed at iis on the local server. If you want to create a virtual directory on the remote iis, you can choose external host